# Why is my shell (sh) variable in command mode not exported?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

If I run a shell command like this my exported variable is not visible.

```
sh -c "export x=100; echo x is $x"
```

I would expect that it outputs "x is 100" but it just say "x is ". If I run this is in an interactive mode it works like expected.

My shell version is: GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$x` get interpreted by the current shell, not the `sh` shell that's you're starting.

Escape it with a backslash:

```
sh -c "export x=100; echo x is \$x"
```

Or use single quotes to prevent the shell from interpreting variables:

```
sh -c 'export x=100; echo x is $x'
```

Comment: If it works for you then please accept the answer so it could be closed. Thanks

Comment: @Utsav: I needed to wait 10 minutes before accepting it (That was actualy new to me but most answers are not that easy to verify as this one so I never met that restriction before).

Comment: Note also that [`export variable=value` is not portable](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193095/where-is-export-var-value-not-available).

Comment: @tripleee It *is* portable (it's in posix, and all vaguely modern shells support it), it just seems to have some quirks in some conditions (which is not quite the same as being "not portable")...

Comment: Your definition of "portable" seems to exclude Solaris and other non-POSIX contemporary systems. I'm not sure it's reasonable to assume the OP subscribes to the same definition, though it's probably better for your sanity if you don't have to be *that* portable.

Comment: @tripleee If we're going to rule out non-posix systems than very little is truly "portable". And the default Solaris 10 shell seems to be the one exception (note that Solaris 11 has been released for a while). In general, "portable" means "compliant with posix".

Comment: You are right, portable shell scripting is hard. This particular piece of code could reasonably be improved with a minor change which allows it to run on every Bourne shell, though.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this particular piece of code doesn't even *need* `export`.